# Does microsoft excel 2016 has function "=googleFinance()" which is available in google sheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, yahoo-finance, stockquotes, google-finance-api

I want to get the live market price(Indian Market) of some stocks which are already mentioned in my MSExcel sheet, which can automatically update. I saw a function in google sheet (=googleFinance()) that does the same thing. But this function is not available in MS EXcel **2016**. How to use this function in MSExcel or are there any alternatives?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: msexcel 2016 @BigBen

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-data-types-stocks-and-geography-61a33056-9935-484f-8ac8-f1a89e210877?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: @PandasINC that is only for excel365, I have msexcel 2016

Comment: Can you make web queries from msexcel 16? You should be able, in the ribon head to data, in data select "get external data" and check from web. If that works you should be able to serach for your stock in google finnace and then import the data. If this doesn't work. Please tell me there are two more methods a bit longer/ complicated.

Comment: Yes, I am able to import the data but this will be a lengthy task, as I want the current price to auto-update every minute. @PandasINC

Answer (score 1):

I did a code that works for me.

```
Function GoogleFinance(index As String)
Dim resultado As Double, ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.navigate "https://www.google.com/finance/quote/" + index + ":BVMF"
Do While ie.busy

DoEvents
Loop
On Error Resume Next
resultado = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("YMlKec fxKbKc")(0).innertext
ie.Quit
GoogleFinance = resultado

End function
```

Comment: Does it still work for you, and how do you run it?

Comment: It does. I run in cell.

Comment: I've added the macros in the VBScripts for macros enabled file, but it returns 0 every time. Any tips what may gone wrong?

Comment: I noticed that I using the stock market of Brazil. Try to changed ":BVMF" to another like: ":NASDAQ"